# How can I detect multidimensional array length in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In the following code the matrix.length only counts the first array and not the second one. How can I count multidimensional array so the result for the following code is 10?

```
var matrix = [1,2,3,4,5,6, [1,2,3,4]];

console.log(matrix.length - 1)
```

Comment: What is expected value that you are looking for?

Comment: You want 10 as a result?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please include the expected result in the described case and also describe the problem in general (this case is pretty specific).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no shortcut, you have to sum up the lengths of the arrays. If you only have two dimensions, then:

```js
var matrix = [1,2,3,4,5,6, [1,2,3,4]];
var sum = matrix.reduce(function(acc, entry) {
    return acc + (Array.isArray(entry) ? entry.length : 1);
}, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

If you may have more dimensions, you'll need recursion. As squint pointed out in a comment, making the above recursive is just a matter of giving our `reduce` callback a name and then doing `reduce` again instead of just using `array.length`:

```js
var matrix = [1,2,3,4,5,6, [1,2,[3,4]]];
var sum = matrix.reduce(function callback(acc, entry) {
    return acc + (Array.isArray(entry) ? entry.reduce(callback, 0) : 1);
}, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

---

Some notes:

- [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) and [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) were added in ES5 (in 2009) and so should be available in just about any modern browser (so, not IE8); they can both be shimmed/polyfilled on older browsers.
- JavaScript doesn't actually have multi-dimensional arrays. It has arrays of arrays.
- The recursive example above uses a construct called a *named function expression* for `callback`. NFEs have a bad name because years ago browsers got them wrong several different ways, but these days they're fine. (If you used the above on IE8 — including polyfills for the things it's missing — even *it* would work even though [IE8 gets NFEs wrong](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html).)

Comment: Just a few extra chars to make it recursive... `entry.length` becomes `entry.reduce(fn, 0)` *(and `fn` for the callback name)*. Might as well go all out!

Comment: @NinaScholz: Where's my head? :-) Thanks.

Comment: @squint: Nice one! Done.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @T.J. Crowder's solution with `reduce`, I would suggest to turn things around a bit so there is only one mention of `reduce` in the code. And to spice it up, this is with arrow syntax:

```js
function entries(a) {
    return Array.isArray(a) ? a.reduce((acc, el) => acc + entries(el), 0) : 1;
}

var matrix = [1,2,3,4,5,6, [1,2, [3,4]]];

console.log(entries(matrix));
```

This way it will even work for non-array arguments: return value is 1 in that case. Obviously not that important.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2019 the answers using reduce are deprecated (or at least there is a better solution to solve it).
Make use of the Array.flat() method to "flatten" the array and take the length of it:

```
var matrix = [1,2,3,4,5,6, [1,2,3,4]];

// this will return you 10
console.log("Length of multidimensional array items: " matrix.flat().length)
```